# Top level setting is overriding file specific setting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, settings, indentation, prettier

I have this user **settings.json** for VSCode (v1.82.0)

```json
{
   "editor.tabSize": 3, // Top-level value.
   "[javascript]": {
      "editor.tabSize": 2,
   },
   "[json]": {
      "editor.tabSize": 5,
   },
   "[yaml]": {
      "editor.tabSize": 4,
   },
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to set file specific `"editor.tabSize"` value but it's always applying the top level value `3` for all files. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it due to indentation detection? what if you set `editor.detectIndentation` to `false`?

Comment: Already tried that but no luck :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.